# jquery find element with html

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div id="TheTable">

  <div class="TheRow">
    <div class="TheID">123</div>
    <div class="TheQuantity">2</div>
    <div class="TheName">test1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="TheRow">
    <div class="TheID">456</div>
    <div class="TheQuantity">3</div>
    <div class="TheName">test2</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And let's say I have 1,000 rows.

I'm writing a function that takes in an ID as parameter and that searches for the TheQuantity and TheName values in the html. Something like this:

```
function GetData(TheID) {

   var TheIndex = $('#TheTable').find("the index of the row that contains TheID")

   TheQuantity = $('#TheTable .TheQuantity').eq(TheIndex);
   TheName = $('#TheTable .TheName').eq(TheIndex);

}
```

I could loop through each .TheID and return the index like this:

```
   $('#TheTable .TheRow').each( function () {
       if ($(this).html() === TheID) { return $(this).index(); }
   });
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more direct way of doing it. Let me know if you have some suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following function will help to get the corresponding data:

```
function GetData(TheID) {

   var IDObj = $('#TheTable .TheID').filter(function(){
       return $.trim($(this).text()) == TheID;
   })

   TheQuantity = IDObj.siblings('.TheQuantity').text();
   TheName = IDObj.siblings('.TheName').text();

}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I edited $(IDObj) to IDObj since var IDObj = $('#TheTable... effectively returns a jquery object.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to add additional attributes to the elements will help search efficiency. For example adding a data attribute

```
 <div class="TheID" data-id="123">123</div>

 var rowIndex= $('.TheID[data-id="'+TheID+'"]').parent().index();
```

For all values:

```
  var row= $('.TheID[data-id="'+TheID+'"]').parent();
  var name= row.find('.TheName').text();
  var qty=row.find('.TheQuantity').text();
```

EDIT: Here's another way using filter method if unable to add attributes to markup:

```
  var row= $('.TheID').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text()==TheID;                              
    }).parent();
  var name= row.find('.TheName').text();
  var qty=row.find('.TheQuantity').text();
```